# Proper way of handling multiple models in a single session

Tags: django

I'm using Django 2.2.1 to create an app to accept applications from one or multiple applicants. When the first applicant finishes entering their info, they can choose to add another applicant so they can get prompted with a similar form still tied to the same application.

My current approach has been creating a hash that will be a field for the application model, then passing that hash through a hidden form between applicants on the same application. This will allow someone to query the existing application with the app hash or create a new app hash when being passed to views.

Is there a more efficient and secure way to handle multiple models within the same session?

In apply/models.py:

```py
def Application(models.Model):
    app_hash = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

In apply/index.html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="h" value="{% if app_hash %} {{app_hash}} {% else %}None{% endif %}">
```

Comment: Have you considered linking your applications together by a ForeignKey?

Comment: @user7733611 I do have an applicant model which has a foreign key connected to the application model. Are you suggesting using the application model primary key as the value passed in the hidden form? I was considering that at first but I wasn't sure if there would be any potential security issues with that implementation.